# How to disable remember_me functionality when using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to disable the remember me functionality. So when when a user closes the web-browser , it should force user to login every time using the credentials.

I came across:

> config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true

in the devise initializer. But I need this functionality when the user closes the browser. Expire all remember_me token when the user closes the webpage. Is there anyway to implement this?

Comment: Remove `rememberable` from the function call to `devise` in `user.rb`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devise is composed of 10 modules out of which `rememberable` is one.

To disable it, remove `rememberable` from the function call to `devise` in `user.rb`(I assume you have a `user`model)